# $\max\{n_1,n_2\} < \max\{m_1,m_2\}$ implies $n_1n_2 > m_1m_2?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory

Suppose we have two sets of natural number $n_1,n_2$ and $m_1,m_2$ such that $$m_1+m_2 = n_1 + n_2$$ and$$\max\{n_1,n_2\} < \max\{m_1,m_2\}.$$ From here can we claim that $$n_1n_2 > m_1m_2?$$

Comment: was that a mistake? it seems trivial question

Comment: Sorry I missed a crucial point. @AvenDesta

Comment: You should to upvote and accept the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG assume $n_1 \le n_2, m_1 \le m_2$, and $m_2=n_2 +d, d>0$, then $m_1=n_1+n_2-(n_2+d)=n_1-d$

$$n_1 n_2 - m_1 m_2 = n_1 n_2 - (n_1-d)(n_2+d)\\ 
= n_1 n_2 -(n_1n_2+n_1d-n_2d-d^2)\\
= d(n_2-n_1)+d^2 >0$$

Comment: What about the example I provided in my answer?

Comment: Oops sorry. I didn't notice the edit in the question. It's strange that the asker did not notify after the edit (that happened after my answer)